# GET socket.io data in JSON

Tags: swift, socket.io

Get in trouble, when I receive data from socket server, it's not correctly formatted, how can transform it to well formatted jSON structure, without equals and semicolons.

```
static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: 
URL(string:"https://myurl.com")!, config: [.log(false), .reconnects(true), .compress, .forcePolling(false), .forceNew(true), .connectParams(["token": "myToken"])])
static let socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/contacts")
 //////////////
 socket.on("connect") { (data, ack) in
       socket.emit("data", data)
       print(data)

    } 
 socket.on("dataR") { (data, ack) in
        print(data)

    }
```

What I receive from socket.io 'print'

```
[<__NSArrayM 0x6000020147b0>(
{
addresses =     (
            {
        address = myAddress;
        currencyCode = BTC;
        id = 1;
        type = wallet;
    }
);
createdDate = "2019-02-06T21:04:13.469Z";
id = 31;
name = Let;
surname = Me;
}
```

Expecting to get well formatted JSON structure to work faraway. Read it all documentation, but I can't deal with it myself.

Comment: That's a `NSMutableArray`, it means that the JSON has already been parsed into Cocoa(Touch) Objects. You can do `let myArray = data as? [String: Any]` on it.

Comment: @Larme Thanks, got it. Topic closed.

Comment: as [[String: Any]] (that’s better)

Comment: @Larme yeah, it's better, thanks you helped me to forward to next task :)